# Several Gulp tasks wait for another one

Tags: javascript, gulp

I need to build a sequence of Gulp tasks like this:

Task1 -> Task2A, Task2B, Task2C -> Task3,

where tasks 2A,2B,2C run in parallel(but task1 should be completed before, and completed just once).

What I tried:

```
gulp.task('Task1', []);

gulp.task('Task2A', ['Task1']);

gulp.task('Task2B', ['Task1']);

gulp.task('Task2C', ['Task1']);

gulp.task('Task3', ['Task2A', 'Task2B', 'Task2C']);
```

Looks like it's working, but I'm not sure, does it guarantee that Task1 will be executed only 1 time, or it can be triggered multiple times?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to do this (without using gulp4.0) is the [run-sequence plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence).

For your case:

```
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build', function(callback) {
   runSequence( 'Task1',
               ['Task2A', 'Task2B', 'Task2C'],
                'Task3',
                callback);
});
```

Make sure you have return statements in all your tasks.

> Please Note
>
> This was intended to be a temporary solution until the release of gulp 4.0 which should have support for defining task dependencies similarly.
>
> Given that Gulp 4 appears to never be fully released, take that for what you will. Be aware that this solution is a hack, and may stop working with a future update to gulp.

Answer (score 0):

Try this structure

```
gulp.task('Task1', []);

gulp.task('Task2A', ['Task1']);

gulp.task('Task2B', ['Task2A']);

gulp.task('Task2C', ['Task2B']);

gulp.task('Task3', ['Task2C']);
```

Also, you can run task inside another task, like this:

```
gulp.task('task1', function(){
  gulp.start('task2');
})
```

Comment: It's not what I need. In your example, Task2A/B/C will run one after another.