# ensure that 'clean' task runs first

Tags: gulp

I have 4 tasks

- clean
- buildSass
- build (depends on buildSass and clean)
- watchSass (triggers buildSass)

Now when I run `build` it triggers both `clean` and `buildSass` at the same time and it's highly unstable as the outcome is random.

How do I ensure that `clean` is run before `buildSass` without adding a dependancy on `clean` in `buildSass`.

If I add a dependancy on `clean` a clean will be triggered every time I modify a scss file and that's not what I want.

Comment: Can you post your code for the `build` task?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence will work for you.  Or gulp 4.0 (in "beta").

Comment: As @Mark suggested you have [run sequence](https://www.npmjs.com/package/run-sequence) plugin for that sort of things or you can tidy up your task, but I need a look at it to be able to help.

Comment: The run sequence plug in did the job, @Mark post it as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I probably shouldn't as I have answered this same question before.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46409698/several-gulp-tasks-wait-for-another-one/46418826#46418826 [you could give me a bump there though ;>}].  The key is that dependent tasks are not run in series but "Note: The tasks will run in parallel (all at once), so don't assume that the tasks will start/finish in order."  From https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname--deps--fn  I use gulp4 which is technically in beta but has been stable for me for a long time and makes this easier.